# Multiple environments in azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, azure-appservice

I am pretty new to Azure API Management so hopefully I am just missing the obvious and there is an easy solution.

I work in a regulated environment where strict validation and code separation is enforced.

For that reason an API that I wrote is implemented on four separate app services each representing a specific environment sandbox, dev,qa, and production

I am trying to set all these up in API Management using custom domains, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Here is where I am at.

API Management has been deployed to its own subnet in a vnet.

I created an internal client certificate, and uploaded it to a vault.  This certificate had multiple subject name alternatives to represent each environment.

```
 Ex. api.contoso.com
     api-sand.contoso.com
     api-dev.contoso.com
     Etc
```

I then created custom domains using this certificate in APIM ...each set as a "gateway" type domain

I then created an Api based on api-dev.contoso.com and a suffix "external" based on the dev app service.  This will host the dev operations that can be exposed to the internet through app gateway

I then created a second api, again using the api-dev.contoso.com custom domain, and specified a suffix of "internal", to host all the internal operations from this api.

I ran into trouble when I tried to create a third API.  This one was supposed to target the sandbox version of the api, but when i started filling out the new api panel, I found that the base url was grayed out and set to api-dev.contoso.com.....there was no way to change it to api-sand.contoso.com

What am I missing?? ...APIM let's you create these custom domains, but it seems to only let you use one...that doesn't seem right....there must be a different approach I need to use.

One option I thought of, but haven't tried yet is to have one custom domain, and implement the environments using different suffixes.   For example api-nonprod.contoso.com/sand/external would link to my sandbox app service, and api-nonprod.contoso.com/dev/external would link to the development app service.

I'd still rather do it through custom domain names if it is possible.

Comment: Apim lets u use the multiple custom domains on the premium sku only and all the apis under the apim instance can be called through any of the custom domains regardless of what u set as default ssl binding under the custom domains blade which is going to show up as the api base url under the api settings

Comment: Thanks Mohamad.   The problem is though,  because I can't edit the base url as I create the new API, I get an error because the path now collides with previous APIs (ie can't have two api-dev.contoso.com/external going to two different app services).... what I want is to create app-sand.contoso.com/external, but it won't let me

Comment: yes, this is by design, you can't specify a domain for a specific api.